# Create-React-app opacity transition is not workiing

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, create-react-app

I am trying to add a opacity transition of an image when mouse hovers over. But it's currently not working and I am not sure why.

I am using:

- create-react-app
- bootstrap 4

**The relevant JS is in Fotter.js, or this:**

```
import React from "react";
import "react-jsx-html-comments";

import "./styles.css";
import logformik from "../../img/formik-mark.png";

class Footer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>inside footer</h1>
        <footer>
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <section className="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-around w-100 sitemap">
              <a href="#" className="nav-home">
                <img src=src={logformik} alt="Formik" width="66" height="58"></img>
              </a>
            </section>
          </nav>
        </footer>
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Footer;
```

**And the relevant CSS is in styles.css, or this:**

```
.sitemap {
  background-color: black;
}

.sitemap h5 {
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-home {
  display: table;
  height: 72px;
  margin: -12px 20px 0 0;
  opacity: 0.4;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 72px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

[image: Image opacity must change]

You can checkout my code and a live demo at this [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/logo-opacity-dont-work-k0sju)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not add hover effect for .nav-home class.

```
.nav-home:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Updated CodeSandBox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ik8s2